# Establishing a constant HTTPS connection between server and client using IIS

Tags: http, ssl, https, server, software-design

I have a single Windows application (.NET) on serving as a **server** and communicating with the database. I also have **client Windows applications (.NET) which communicate with the server application**. Pretty standard so far.

As of now, I am using the IP address of the server, say "192.168.1.114", which I enter in my client software to establish the link. For instance,  "http://192.168.1.114".

Now, I am trying to change that connection to HTTPS. Is there any way I can do that without actually changing the codebase? (I don't have the source code)

Any IIS certificate? Require SSL? Machine Key? Binding? Anything! I just want those packets to not be transmitted with regular HTTP. 
Thank you so much, dear Community.

Comment: If you really enter the `http:` part, enter `https:` instead. Off topic.

Comment: That doesn't work. The client application gives an error suggesting it failed to connect to the server.